# How to check if multiple lags of a (grouped) variable meet a condition using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, case, lag

I'm analysing certain weather events occuring in certain regions across several years. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(region = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
             event = c(rep("storm", 5), rep("rain", 5), rep("storm", 5), rep("rain", 5)),
             year = c(rep(1:5, 4)),
             occured = c("n", "n", "y", "n", "y",
                         "y", "n", "n", "n", "y",
                         "n", "y", "y", "y", "y",
                         "n", "n", "n", "n", "y")
             )
```

I now want to create an indicator variable that tells me whether a certain weather event has occured in a certain region for the first time in x years.

Let's say I'm interested in the past two years, then following code achieves this:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(region, event) %>% 
   mutate(ind = case_when(
     occured == "y" &
       lag(occured, 1, default = "n") == "n" &
       lag(occured, 2, default = "n") == "n" ~ 1,
     .default = 0
     )
     )


# A tibble: 20 × 5
# Groups:   region, event [4]
   region event  year occured   ind
   <chr>  <chr> <int> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A      storm     1 n           0
 2 A      storm     2 n           0
 3 A      storm     3 y           1
 4 A      storm     4 n           0
 5 A      storm     5 y           0
 6 A      rain      1 y           1
 7 A      rain      2 n           0
 8 A      rain      3 n           0
 9 A      rain      4 n           0
10 A      rain      5 y           1
11 B      storm     1 n           0
12 B      storm     2 y           1
13 B      storm     3 y           0
14 B      storm     4 y           0
15 B      storm     5 y           0
16 B      rain      1 n           0
17 B      rain      2 n           0
18 B      rain      3 n           0
19 B      rain      4 n           0
20 B      rain      5 y           1
```

My question: could anybody tell me of a more efficient and flexible way of creating this indicator variable?

It would be great to have a solution which doesn't require me to go add or delete multiple lag statements depending on the number of years I'm interested in.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `slide_dbl` to count the number of "y" values in a rolling window and check it's only once, in the current row.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ind = 1 * (occured == "y" &
           slider::slide_dbl(occured == "y", sum, .before = 2) == 1),
         .by = c(region, event))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `reduce` from `purrr` package:

`reduce` checks for each iteration (.y) whether the lagged occured is "n" and combines this with the result from the previous step (.x) using a logical AND operation.

`1:2` is year one to two, if you want more just change to for example `1:3`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(ind = ifelse(occured == "y" & reduce(1:2, ~ .x & (lag(occured, .y, default = "n") == "n"), .init = TRUE), 1, 0), .by = c(region, event))
```

```
  region event  year occured   ind
   <chr>  <chr> <int> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A      storm     1 n           0
 2 A      storm     2 n           0
 3 A      storm     3 y           1
 4 A      storm     4 n           0
 5 A      storm     5 y           0
 6 A      rain      1 y           1
 7 A      rain      2 n           0
 8 A      rain      3 n           0
 9 A      rain      4 n           0
10 A      rain      5 y           1
11 B      storm     1 n           0
12 B      storm     2 y           1
13 B      storm     3 y           0
14 B      storm     4 y           0
15 B      storm     5 y           0
16 B      rain      1 n           0
17 B      rain      2 n           0
18 B      rain      3 n           0
19 B      rain      4 n           0
20 B      rain      5 y           1
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `lag` use `diff` after subsetting accordingly:

```
df %>%
    group_by(region, event)%>%
    mutate(ind = occured=='y', 
           ind = +(ind * replace(year, ind , diff(c(-Inf, year[ind]))) > 2))
# A tibble: 20 × 5
# Groups:   region, event [4]
   region event  year occured   ind
   <chr>  <chr> <int> <chr>   <int>
 1 A      storm     1 n           0
 2 A      storm     2 n           0
 3 A      storm     3 y           1
 4 A      storm     4 n           0
 5 A      storm     5 y           0
 6 A      rain      1 y           1
 7 A      rain      2 n           0
 8 A      rain      3 n           0
 9 A      rain      4 n           0
10 A      rain      5 y           1
11 B      storm     1 n           0
12 B      storm     2 y           1
13 B      storm     3 y           0
14 B      storm     4 y           0
15 B      storm     5 y           0
16 B      rain      1 n           0
17 B      rain      2 n           0
18 B      rain      3 n           0
19 B      rain      4 n           0
20 B      rain      5 y           1
```